# Gradient Picture as background causes massive performance issues

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-drawable

My android app has one fragment represented by a `ScrollView` containing a `LinearLayout`. The `ScrollView` itself is put in a `RelativeLayout` to ensure that the background picture won't stretch.

My problem is I recently had to change the former background picture ( basically a random picture of the sky ) for one with a gradient, from grey to white. This picture is very light ( only 20kb ) and it's jpeg format. Those pictures were converted from a 1mb sized png. This problem happen randomly and some pictures with gradient but not with others...

The trouble is that it give massive performance troubles while used as a background. I'm almost reaching a few frame per second using it, while it was perfecting clean and smooth with the former one.

Is it something wrong when using pictures with gradient when I'm using android? How can I avoid those performances drop?

Comment: most likely your UI tree is too complex (too deep)

Comment: I don't think so, as said with some other gradient picture I have this trouble while with some others, it is smooth. My app doesn't contain too deep elements so the tree complexity of my app is not responsible for sure.

Comment: well, i think nobody will help you reading just the problem symptoms

Comment: There's probably some issues linked to the gradient use with android that I don't know. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: imho without your code, you will get to response

Comment: It has nothing to do with the code I think, everything happened when I modified a background. Using a different on even ten times heavier fix the problem. But just because the picture is a gradient, I have performance issues.

Comment: if you think it has nothing to do with the code then i cannot add anything else